# Variable value does not change

Tags: python, function, variables

I am starting to learn Python and I can't get my program to work because there is a problem with variables.
I have a file named 'Variables.py' that contains the following code :

```
import locale

DeviceLanguage = None

def SetLanguage():
    DeviceLanguage = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
```

And the main file contains this code:

```
import Variables as Vars

Vars.SetLanguage()
print(Vars.DeviceLanguage)
```

But the console displays None whereas when I debug the function SetLanguage(), DeviceLanguage changes value.

I want to keep this organization because SetLanguage() actually contains a lot more variables and it helps to make my program structured and organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark veriable as global

```py
import locale

DeviceLanguage = None

def SetLanguage():
    global DeviceLanguage
    DeviceLanguage = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
```

```py
import Variables as Vars

Vars.SetLanguage()
print(Vars.DeviceLanguage)
```

this will print the desired value.